# SelectableItemBackground not working with actionbar style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-custom-attributes

I am trying to change the hit state colour of the actionable items on the action bar. On my nexus 7 (4.3) the default colour for the hit state is a Turquoise blue. On my nexus 4 (4.4) the hit state is holo_light. Even after setting the 'android:selectableItemBackground' to holo_light I am seeing the turquoise blue on button press on my nexus 7.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
 <style name="CustomActionBarStyle"    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_image_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/bg_image_actionbar_stacked</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/layer_actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector_custom_action_bar_selectable_item_bg</item>
 </style>
```

The xml for custom selector is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item                                                                                          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Can somebody point out what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this issue. I had to add another style "android:listViewStyle"